# How to Update particular Panda's DataFrame record with pd.random.randint() using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, jupyter-notebook

we have below `df.Age.value_counts()` in our pandas.DataFrame:

```
25-34 years old       2365
35-44 years old       1048
18-24 years old        626
45-54 years old        343
55-64 years old         98
```

How can we update each record with `np.random.randint(25,34)`

```
for i in x.columns:
    if df[i][1] == '25-34 years old':
        df[i][1] = np.random.randint(25,34)
        ?????
```

i had also tried

```
df.loc[x['Age'] == '25-34 years old','Age'] = np.random.randint(25,34)
```

but it only updates same random value for each `'25-34 years old'` record, means if random function returns 27 then these 2365 rows will get Age = 27 only

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask to extract index and size to create the new series with random numbers...

Example:

```
data = {'Age': ["25-34 years old", "25-34 years old", "20-24 years old", "20-24 years old", "25-34 years old", "25-34 years old", "25-34 years old", "20-25 years old", "35-45 years old", "35-45 years old", "20-25 years old", "20-25 years old", "35-45 years old", "35-45 years old", "20-25 years old", "20-25 years old"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = df[df.Age == "25-34 years old"]

df.loc[mask.index,"Age"] = np.random.randint(25, 35, size=mask.shape[0])

df
```

Output:

```
          Age
0   31
1   31
2   20-24 years old
3   20-24 years old
4   25
5   28
6   32
7   20-25 years old
8   35-45 years old
9   35-45 years old
10  20-25 years old
11  20-25 years old
12  35-45 years old
13  35-45 years old
14  20-25 years old
15  20-25 years old
```

Other option would be replace all values in the column to create a function that extract the range from the string an uses it to create a random number. You can make it as follows...

```
def create_age(row):
    age_range = row.Age.split(" ")[0].split("-")
    return np.random.randint(int(age_range[0]),int(age_range[1])+1)

df["Age"] = df.apply(create_age,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Age
0   28
1   26
2   24
3   24
4   26
5   33
6   25
7   23
8   39
9   41
10  24
11  25
12  42
13  39
14  24
15  20
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you can use apply to operate row-wise:

```
df['Age'] = df[['Age']].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(*x.values[0][:5].split('-')), axis=1)
```